# como puedo crear una nueva celda usando fpdf?

Tags: fpdf

estoy trantando de insertar una nueva celda justo debajo de la celda ganancia donde solo se muestre 1 valor y no sea repetido a lo largo del documento pdf

```
// Creaciacion del objeto de la clase heredada
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'Letter');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$header = array('ID','Usuario','Departamento','Recargado','Servicio','tu0','Comision','#Servicio','Venta','Fecha','Hora','Ganancia total');
$ancho  = array(7,25,30,20,20,12,20,30,20,25,25);
foreach ($header as $key => $value){

    $pdf->Cell($ancho[$key],7,$value,1, 0, 'C');
}
$pdf->Ln();


$pdf->Cell($ancho[0],7,utf8_decode($resultado['id']),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[1],7,utf8_decode($resultado_usuario['personaNombre']),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[2],7,utf8_decode($resultado_usuario['nombreDepartamento']),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[3],7,utf8_decode($resultado['recarga']),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[4],7,utf8_decode($solicitud),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[5],7,utf8_decode($p15),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[6],7,utf8_decode($p15),1, 0, 'C');    
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[7],7,utf8_decode(substr($resultado['titulo'],0,14)),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[8],7,utf8_decode($resultado['prioridad']),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[9],7,utf8_decode($fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[10],7,utf8_decode($hora),1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell($ancho[11],7,utf8_decode($p15),1, 0, 'C');   
    $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output('tickets pendientes','I',1);
```

ya he logrado mostrar los datos traidos de mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero quiero quitar la segunda y mostrar en el cuadro de arriba la suma del total(ya lo tengo) 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

lo pude solucionar haciendo la impresion de una nueva tabla luego de terminar la linea del header

```
$pdf->Ln();


//codigo nueva celda
$pdf->SetY(37);
$pdf->SetX(234);
$pdf->Cell(30,7,utf8_decode($p15),1,1,'C');
```